# Is it correct to compare two distributions of observed (that are means of observation) and expected values with chi square?

Tags: self-study, classification, chi-squared-test, unbalanced-classes, method-comparison

I have 2 classification methods that I want to compare. So I ran them on the same dataset and I obtained 2 different classifications.

Then, I want to test if their classification is robust and how. Supposing each classification gives $n$ classes, for each method (classification):

- I created $m$ datasets for each class, where the class is cut to a half (50%).
  So I have $m$ datasets for class $i$, where half of the item classified as $i$ in the complete classification are removed; $m$ datasets for class $i+1$; and so on.
- I ran each method on its $nm$ datasets and I obtained $nm$ different classifications.

Now I want to check if one of the two competitors, given that for each class I removed half of samples in at least one run, tends to classify always the same proportion of samples. For example:

```
Complete-Classification    1   2   1   1   3   2   1
```

If I cut half of class 1, I have 2 items classified as 1.

```
Remaining samples          1   2           3   2   1
```

If I run one of the methods again (but in one new dataset without the two samples - like that just shown) I am expecting to obtain a number of 1-classified samples that is near to 2, because I know from the complete classification that there should be 2 samples classified as 1.

In fact, this is not the case, each one of the two methods tends to balance the distribution, classifying more than 2 samples as 1.

Also, I test $m$ different datasets for class 1, such as

```
Remaining samples             2    1       3   2   1

Remaining samples             2    1   1   3   2
```

in order to better estimate the effect using different samples.

Given that I want to penalize the method that overestimate the class cut, what can I do?

I thougth about:

- I know that for class $i$ I expect $k$ classified items;
- I calculate the mean of the estimates for each class (I do not know if it is correct here to think that the distribution is normal - but I think it is reasonable);
- For each method I have, expected values (half-size of the classes in the complete classification) and observed values (mean of the estimates for each class).

Now, I am stuck. I am thinking to:

- Use $\chi^2$ test (assuming the normality of the distribution of estimates, for each class);
- Alternatively, for each class compute the fold-change between mean of estimates and "correct" value; but here I do not know how to summarize the $n$ fold-changes to a unique value.

What method do you suggest?

Hope it is clear. Thanks